# How to get started with jQuery Mobile? (Programmers background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a background in C++/C# and Java (Android). Now, I want to pick up what seems to me the best solution for mobile web applications: jQuery Mobile.

I know some of the very basics of HTML/DOM/CSS, but not in a structured/thorough manner.
Javascript-wise, it seems to be a rather different programming approach than I'm used to.

Where do you recommend I start? Javascript (and possibly Ajax) or jQuery or could I afford by immediately starting with jQuery mobile?
Plus, could you recommend me some good learning/example sources as well?

Thank you in advance.

-Thomas

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery mobile is a plugin written using jQuery in order to Enhance html5 elements appearance and behaviour to match iPhone design pattern for application behaviour (Progressive enhancement).

Whilst it is fairly easy to get started filling the templates jQMobile provides as a C# developer you need to understand that working with JavaScript and jQuery has some significant differences.

jQuery was a community necessity and is basically nothing but an abstraction layer on top of JavaScript to rectify the difficulties programmers were facing which mainly had to do with the difference of JavaScript implementation in different browsers and also the weakness in the DOM which is an API which allows JavaScript to access elements inside the document.

What jQ basically does is it takes care of those differences for you and exposes methods to you that are pretty much guaranteed to deliver the same results across supported browsers.

This will greatly help you get started by still wont allow you to learn the fundamental differences between the world you are coming from and the world you are getting into.

JS does not have classes only functions. However functions can have methods and be instantiated. The inheritance in js is Prototypal Inheritance.

```
new f()
```

produces a new object that inherits from

```
f.prototype
```

[more info here](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

To learn the basics and understand more about this language before you use it! [please watch this also](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook)

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I'll start by diving into JS essential differences first. What would be the logical step afterwards: study jQ or jump right into jQM?

Comment: there isn't much to learn about jQm. its just templates which you drop stuff in. Learn JS and then JQ. Then you can use JQM